# Consulta Select Mysql Respuesta y esa respuesta en otra consulta

Tags: mysql, mysqli

necesito ayuda en el siguiente problema, tengo un Select en MySQL y necesito que esa respuesta pueda ponerse dentro de un NOT IN de otra consulta.

Estas son las query:

```
    SELECT id
        FROM notas
        WHERE web = '1'
            AND borrado = '0'
            AND portadacategoria = '1'
        ORDER by id DESC
            LIMIT 0,10
```

La respuesta de esta consulta deberia ir en el NOT IN de esta otra consulta:

```
             SELECT nota.id, 
               nota.web, 
               nota.destacado, 
               nota.fechanota, 
               nota.portadacategoria, 
               nota.categorianota,
               DATE_FORMAT(nota.fechanota,'%d/%m/%Y') AS fechanota, 
               nota.permalink, 
               nota.titulo, 
               nota.cabecera, 
               nota.phportada, 
               nota.copete, 
               nota.borrado,
               cat.nombrecat
        FROM notas nota
        JOIN categorias cat
        ON nota.categorianota = cat.idcat
        WHERE cat.portadacat = '1'
        AND nota.web = '1' 
        AND nota.borrado = '0' 
        AND nota.categorianota = '2' 
        AND nota.id NOT IN() 
        ORDER by nota.id DESC
```

¿Es posible unirlo a través de MySQL? 
Muchas gracias!

Comment: Claro, simplemente agrega el primer código (quita el ORDER by y el LIMIT) dentro de los paréntesis. Es es todo, si has tenido algún problema nos dices.

Comment: Y por cierto, Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Muchas gracias!, pude resolverlo!